# Trying to remember an older planetary romance novel

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am trying to remember a book that I read fairly recently, although it was much older (from the 1970s at the latest).  I probably found a copy of it online somewhere like the Internet Archive.  It wasn't particularly good, but it did have one rather memorable scene that I would like to look at again.  It was by a fairly minor author, somebody that I had probably never read before—or maybe never even heard of before.  (It was not one of the Barsoom/John Carter novels by Edgar Rice Burroughs; I never managed to finish *A Princess of Mars*.  Nor, I'm fairly confident, was it one of the Dray Prescot novels by Alan Burt Akers, a. k. a. Kenneth Bulmer.  Not Jack Vance or Leigh Brackett either.  And it sure wasn't anything by John Norman.)  It was typical mid-century paperback length, about 200 pages, and I have a vague idea that the main color on the cover was blue.

The plot was a fairly standard planetary romance.  The beefy hero gets transported from Earth to another planet by some vaguely mystical force, and after he gets there he needs to retrieve an artifact from an illusionary pyramid.  (I think the walls appear to be solid but don't actually exist.)  However, the artifact does not, from what I remember, actually play much of a role in the rest of the story.

The main character wanders for a while, until he finds a ruined city.  A beautiful (apparently human) woman flies by on a rocket sled, being chased by a group of soldiers, who may or may not also be human.  The hero kills them somehow (maybe by shooting down their sleds), and the woman reveals she is a princess who has they were trying to abduct and force to marry the lord of another realm.  The two of them naturally fall in love and end up traveling together.

However, they are captured, maybe by the same group that was chasing her.  The prison they are placed in is not very secure, however, and they escape with relative ease, passing through a museum of ancient technology and then the spacious sewers.  In the sewers, they meet up with a sleeping vampire (although not called by the name "vampire" in the text; it used a made-up term instead).  Everyone from the planet is utterly terrified of the vampires, but this one wakes up and seems pretty nice.  He offers to help them, in fact.  (Maybe he knows the location of a second matching artifact, if the hero will kill a certain monster for him.)

They set off for the island where this monster lives, and this is the part I definitely liked.  Amidst the ruins atop of the rocky cliffs, where the vampire drops the hero off, the hero is attacked by a yellow-scaled, four-armed giant.  The hero doesn't look like he stands much of a chance, but he puts for a tremendous effort and gets in a skillful (or lucky) blow that should seriously wound the creature.  However, it just shrugs it off, and, in fact, every wound the hero manages to inflict—and he is puzzling able to avoid getting killed for quite a while—heals completely.  I think it even looses and arm, but puts it right back in place again (like the proto-D & D troll in *Three Hearts and Three Lions*).  Eventually, the main character realizes that the monster is just an illusion, created by the vampire's psychic powers, as a way to distract him while the vampire sails off with the princess!

After that, the hero somehow gets ahold of another rocket sled and goes after the princess.  There is at least one small but bloody battle, maybe when he locates and rescues her.  However, by this time, the sister of the enemy lord she was going to be forced to marry has become so impressed with the hero that she decides to give up on the marriage plan and ally with the main characters, so that everyone left alive can have a happy ending.

Does anyone remember this?

Comment: Wow. All that in one short novel.

Comment: This question is a little terse and could be improved by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum If there were other details I remembered apart from the plot, I probably would have found it already myself.

Comment: @Buzz - It would, for example, be very helpful if you could tell us the name of the book and who wrote it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the *LOL* at the end.

Comment: Sounds very much in the vein of Edgar Rice Burroughs - perhaps something in the *John Carter* series?

Comment: Yes this sounds like *A Princess of Mars*, the first John Carter book. The princess of course is Dejah Thoris.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I thought the same thing, but I don't remember the museum or the sewer vampire.  It's been decades, though, since I read it.

Comment: It wasn't *A Princess of Mars*, but that was undoubtedly an influence.  I added mention of another couple of planetary romance series that it wasn't.

Comment: Something by Lin Carter maybe? Sounds like one of his "homages" to Burroughs.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That sounds like a possibility.  I avoided Lin Carter for a long time, based on the weakness of his Conan stories, but I remember thinking about giving him another chance.

Comment: I couldn't really read his stuff either, which is why I don't have a definite suggestion. He made a great contribution by editing the Ballantine Adult Fantasy series so props for that, but sheesh, his own stuff was lethal.